# How do I create and manage a local git branch, and ignore certain working files?

Tags: git

I have a team project on gitlab.
I periodically add contributions and push these to the remote repo. Usually, these are newly created files.

However, I have working files (python scripts, notebooks) which I do not want to push. I can often not place this outside of the local repo (for example, as I need to be within a scrapy project to crawl the web, intermediate outputs will be saved within the scrapy project, thus within the local git repo).

Currently, before adding a commit, I go through the local git repo and relocate any files that I do not want to push. However, this is tedious and worsens my overview of the project.
I considered creating a local branch - however, as far as I understand, this will not solve my problem of not wanting to push every file to the remote repo.

What is the correct way to manage such a repository, so that I only push files I want to, but not intermediate files and working scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring files in git can be done via `.gitignore`. See official docs for details https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.

The concept is as follows:

- Just add a file named `.gitignore` to your repo and fill it with things to ignore
- You can add complete file names: myFileToIgnore.fileExtension
- You can add extensions: *.myFileExtensionToIgnore
- You can ignore folders: My/Folder/To/Ignore
- You can mix things
- Depending on your programing language and tooling, you often find pretty good `.gitignore` templates online for your project

You choose what fits best for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is why there is an *index*. A commit, when you create one by saying `git commit`, consists of exactly what's in the index. As long as you never `git add` these files to the index, they will never be committed. Such files are called *untracked* and will appear under that heading when you say `git status`.